# Scroll/pan ggplotly with title

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

I use ggplotly in my shiny app and use the layout function for the title. When I want to pan the picture, the title and images stay on the same spot while the plot is moving.

Is there a way to let them move with the plot? I know the pan function is to look at parts of the plotted values, but I also got info in the images and title. Besides that, I want the plot to be a certain size, even on mobile and than I need the plot to be able to scroll.

MRE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

plot<- ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
ggplotly(
  plot,tooltip="text")%>%
  layout(title = list(hjust= 0.5,text = "Title"))
```

Adding the title through ggplot doesn't solve this.

EDIT:
I made a scrollable box, which solves it a little bit. I want to use the whole plot to scroll when there is a finger/cursor clicking and moving.

Otherwise an other solution is just setting the aspect ratio of the plot instead of the absolute size. Anyone know something about that?